# Obj-C Variable Stack Type

Tags: objective-c, pointers, stack

As a foray into new programming languages, I build well known data structures to familiarize myself with the syntax and the basic ins & outs of the language. In this case, I examine the stack in Objective-C.  From Apple's *Working with Objects* we read about the keyword 'id'

> ...This is a special keyword used in Objective-C to mean “some kind of object.” It is a pointer to an object, like (NSObject *), but is special in that it doesn’t use an asterisk.

By using the keyword 'id', it seems possible to create a stack data structure that holds differing types of Obj-C objects; however, I am not sure if this as intended.  Is it better to create the various class methods for each potential data type rather than attempting a generic method and make sure each stack adheres to a single Object type?.  Here is what I have so far

XYZNode.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYZNode : NSObject

@property id value;

@property XYZNode *next;

-(instancetype)initWithValue:(id)aValue next:(XYZNode *)aNext;

-(instancetype)init;

//  Class factory methods should always start with the name of 
//  the class (without the prefix) that they create, with the 
//  exception of subclasses of classes with existing factory methods.
+(XYZNode *)nodeWithValue:(id)aValue nextNode:(XYZNode *)aNext;

@end
```

XYZNode.m

```
#import "XYZNode.h"

@implementation XYZNode

-(instancetype)initWithValue:(id)aValue next:(XYZNode *)aNext {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        _value = aValue;
        _next = aNext;
    } return self;

}

-(instancetype)init {

    return [self initWithValue:nil next:nil];

}

+(XYZNode *)nodeWithValue:(id)aValue nextNode:(XYZNode *)aNext {

    return [[self alloc] initWithValue:aValue next:aNext];

}

@end
```

XYZStack.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYZStack : NSObject

-(void)pushValue:(id)aValue;

-(id)popValue;

-(BOOL)isEmpty;

-(instancetype)init;

-(instancetype)initWithValue:(id)aValue;

+(XYZStack *)stackWithValue:(id)aValue;

@end
```

XYZStack.m

```
#import "XYZStack.h"

#import "XYZNode.h"

// The extension hides how the values are stored
@interface XYZStack ()

@property XYZNode *lastNodeAdded;

@end

@implementation XYZStack

// Default initializer
-(instancetype)initWithValue:(id)aValue {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        _lastNodeAdded = nil;

    }

    if (aValue) {

        [self pushValue:aValue];

    }

    return self;
}

// Call default initializer
-(instancetype)init{

    return [self initWithValue:nil];
}

-(BOOL)isEmpty{

    return ([self lastNodeAdded] == nil);

}

-(void)pushValue:(id)aValue {

    [self setLastNodeAdded:[XYZNode nodeWithValue:aValue nextNode:[self lastNodeAdded]]];

}

-(id)popValue {

    id temp = [[self lastNodeAdded] value];

    [self setLastNodeAdded:[[self lastNodeAdded] next]];

    return temp;

}

+(XYZStack *)stackWithValue:(id)aValue {

    return [[self alloc] initWithValue:aValue];

}

@end
```

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: An NSMutableArray can be used to create a stack.  It is an array of type `id`.  It is usual in Objective-C (given that it's a "duck typed" language) to deal with pointers of type `id`.

Comment: All of the standard collections classes use `id`. BTW - your `init` methods should have a return type of `instancetype`, not `id`.

Comment: In Apple's Concepts in Objective-C programming, (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html) the examples of initialization prefixed with init have a return type of 'id'.  Is this a misunderstanding on my part?  Couldnt find a reference explicitly stating such.

Comment: That's probably an old reference. Init methods used to return id, but now it's best to use instancetype. Look at the document, "Adopting Modern Objective-C" for an explanation of its use.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I made the appropriate changes.